# Delete iOS runtimes in Xcode 9.4

Tags: ios, xcode, runtime, simulator

I need to delete and reinstall my iOS runtimes in Xcode 9.4

But all of the help I've found online must be for older versions of Xcode. They all say the runtimes are in `/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes` but on my system that folder doesn't exist

Furthermore, iOS 11.4 is not listed in Preferences > Components. It's the one I'm having most problems with. How do I uninstall and reinstall it?

What's going on ??

[image]

[image]

Comment: did you ever get anywhere with this?